# When in consent necessary for touching someone?

Tags: canada, battery, human-rights, rape

When is consent to touch another person necessary and what constitutes consent? This question focuses on intimate, romantic or sexual relationships between two adults. At school they have been pushing the [Consent is Sexy](http://www.consentissexy.net/) motto and I was wondering what exact words need to be used and what situations they apply to?

Obviously no means no and rape is rape. But I've heard of situations where after the fact the female claims she was exploited without consent and the male claims he didn't intend to. For example does a husband literally need to say the words "do you want to have sex?" to his wife and if she doesn't reply "yes" it's technically illegal?

Does context matter? E.g. is running up to a stranger and kissing them illegal but kissing your partner isn't without consent?

A made up example: I met a girl on a dating website and she later complained I didn't get consent to hold her hand but she never said not to or resisted. I also kissed her and she kissed me back and later complained I didn't get consent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Criminal Code says:

> 265. (1) A person commits an assault when (a) without the consent of another person, he applies force intentionally to that other person,
>        directly or indirectly

Touching is applying force, even if it is slight. The law also says (same section) that apparent consent evidenced by submission isn't actually consent:

> (3) For the purposes of this section, no consent is obtained where the
>   complainant submits or does not resist by reason of
>
> (a) the application of force to the complainant or to a person other
>   than the complainant;
>
> (b) threats or fear of the application of force to the complainant or
>   to a person other than the complainant;
>
> (c) fraud; or
>
> (d) the exercise of authority.

This pretty much means that consent is always required. If you are wrong about there having been consent and you end up being charged, you can explain why you thought there was consent, and the judge may find the story sufficiently plausible that you can use that as a defence, because:

> 4) Where an accused alleges that he believed that the complainant
>   consented to the conduct that is the subject-matter of the charge, a
>   judge, if satisfied that there is sufficient evidence and that, if
>   believed by the jury, the evidence would constitute a defence, shall
>   instruct the jury, when reviewing all the evidence relating to the
>   determination of the honesty of the accused's belief, to consider the
>   presence or absence of reasonable grounds for that belief.

Here is a [model jury instruction](https://www.nji-inm.ca/index.cfm/publications/model-jury-instructions/assaults-and-other-non-fatal-offences-against-the-person/offence-266-assault/) pertaining to consent

> Third – Did (NOC) consent to the force that (NOA) applied? To decide
>   whether (NOC) consented to the physical contact, you must consider
>   (NOC)’s state of mind. Consider all the evidence, including the
>   circumstances surrounding (NOA)’s physical contact with (NOC), to
>   decide whether (NOC) consented to it. Take into account any words or
>   gestures, whether by (NOA) or (NOC), and any other indication of
>   (NOC)’s state of mind at the time. Just because (NOC) submitted or did
>   not resist does not mean that (NOC) consented to what (NOA) did.
>   Consent requires (NOC)’s voluntary agreement, without the influence of
>   force, threats, fear, fraud or abuse of authority, to let the physical
>   contact occur.

The instruction pertaining to the "honest but mistaken belief in consent" defence goes like this:

> (NOA)’s position is that s/he was unaware that (NOC) did not consent.
>   In fact, it is his/her position that s/he honestly believed that (NOC)
>   consented to the physical contact in question. A belief is a state of
>   mind, in this case, (NOA)’s state of mind. To determine whether (NOA)
>   honestly believed that (NOC) consented to the physical contact in
>   question, you should consider all the circumstances surrounding that
>   activity. Take into account any words or gestures, whether by (NOA) or
>   (NOC), and any other indication of (NOA)’s state of mind at the time.
>   (NOA)’s belief that (NOC) consented to the physical contact must be an
>   honest belief, but it does not have to be reasonable. However, you
>   must consider whether there were reasonable grounds for (NOA)’s
>   belief; the presence or absence of reasonable grounds may help you
>   decide whether (NOA)’s belief was honest. Look at all the
>   circumstances in deciding this issue. Do not focus on only one and
>   ignore the rest. You must consider all the evidence, including
>   anything said or done in the circumstances. Use common sense. (NOA)
>   does not have to prove that s/he honestly believed that (NOC)
>   consented to the physical contact. Rather, the Crown must prove beyond
>   a reasonable doubt that (NOA) had no such belief.

In other words, if the story is believable, the jury might believe it. Asking for each and every kind of contact can be annoying and a little silly, but if you might be at risk, better silly than sorry.

Comment: If consent is always required for any physical touch, then what exactly is consent and can it be implied? For example can you sue someone for shaking your hand because you didn't verbally say "want to shake hands?"

Comment: Also what about sports? When people play football they don't ask each other "is it ok for me to tackle you" so is it implied with the activity?

Comment: @Mahones WRT handshakes, one typically holds out a hand for the other to grasp. It's hard to imagine how one party could later deny consent. If the person who didn't initiate the handshake doesn't want to participate, he or she can simply refrain from accepting the offered handshake.

Comment: Much of consent is implied by activities. By playing football, you agree (by your actions) to be touched. Verbal consent is not required, what is required is an action that a reasonable person would understand to be consent. Holding your hand out and at the moment of contact shrieking "Assault! I didn't verbally consent to being touched!" will not persuade a reasonable jury.

Comment: "Holding your hand out and at the moment of contact shrieking "Assault! I didn't verbally consent to being touched!" will not persuade a reasonable jury": but will it sway the referee?

Comment: Also patting someone on the back or tapping someones shoulder to get their attention would seem to be a form of assault as per this definition. Is it that courts take into consideration social norms and wouldn't apply the definition rigorously?

Comment: Yes, via mistaken belief in consent. There are a few religion-based contexts where you might know otherwise, but generally we assume that a person would want to know that they dropped their wallet. If a person is wearing a sign saying "Never touch me!", then you know something is up.

Comment: @user6726 "Much of consent is implied by activities." which clearly, in the real world, applies to intimacy too. Don't sit in someone's lap if you don't want that person's hands on your body. Don't share a bed with someone you don't want to make out with. Etc. The other way around - where you have to ask about every step - would be completely unattractive.